# Execute multiple exchange online cmdlets using C# , ASP.NET with only 1 runspace

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell, exchange-server

I am working on a ASP.Net webapplication that can connect to Exchange Online and run the commandlets.

The following is the working codebehind for a single button, which gets list of all the mailboxes in asp.net

```
protected void FinalConnection_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String userName = "";
        String passWord = "";
        SecureString securestring = new SecureString();

        foreach (char pass in passWord) {
            securestring.AppendChar(pass);
        }

        PSCredential pscred = new PSCredential(userName,securestring);
        WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri("https://ps.outlook.com/powershell"), "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange", pscred);
        connectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Basic;
        connectionInfo.MaximumConnectionRedirectionCount = 2;

        using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo))
        {
            runspace.Open();
            using (PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                powershell.Runspace = runspace;
                //Create the command and add a parameter
                powershell.AddCommand("Get-Mailbox");
                //var script = "Get-Mailbox";
                //powershell.AddScript(script);
                //powershell.AddParameter("RecipientTypeDetails", "UserMailbox");
                //Invoke the command and store the results in a PSObject collection
                var results = powershell.Invoke();
                //Iterate through the results and write the DisplayName and PrimarySMTP
                //address for each mailbox
                foreach (PSObject result in results)
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Name: {0}, PrimarySmtpAddress: {1}",
                    //        result.Properties["DisplayName"].Value.ToString(),
                    //        result.Properties["PrimarySmtpAddress"].Value.ToString()
                    //        ));

                    newpowershell.InnerHtml += result.Properties["Name"].Value;

                }
            }
            runspace.Close();
        } 
    }
```

I want to create different buttons like "Get-Users" "Get-MSOLUsers", but i want to keep only one runspace because of the throttling restrictions, max runspace = 3;

Should i open and close runspace for every button ? That is not a correct idea i believe

Can you please suggest alternatives on this?

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem?? If so please post the answer here!

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the runspace open and create a new pipeline (`runspace.CreatePipeline`) each time you need to run a script.  I'm not sure if it's threadsafe though. You may need to limit the runspace to 1 open pipeline at a time.